# Linux Azure web app service remote debugging

Tags: ssh, azure-web-app-service, sftp, visual-studio-2022

The only known way to debug a Linux Azure web app is to create a TCP tunnel between your machine and Azure which is explained [here](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/05/07/New-SSH-Experience-and-Remote-Debugging-for-Linux-Web-Apps.html).

I am able to create the tunnel, SSH and SFTP into the web app using the credentials given from Azure(127.0.0.1 and port) via terminal but having problems with adding the connection to Debug -> Attach to Process in Visual Studio 2022. The response is 'Could not connect to the remote system, connection timed out' and the stack is:

```
11:24:25.4599569 [Info, Thread 1]   liblinux.RemoteSystemBase: Connecting over SSH to 127.0.0.1:63718
11:24:26.0743705 [Info, Thread 1]   liblinux.IO.RemoteFileSystemImpl: Connecting over SFTP to 127.0.0.1:63718
11:24:56.0883458 [Info, Thread 1]   liblinux.HostKeyVerifier: Connection failed.
11:24:56.0883458 [Info, Thread 1]   liblinux.HostKeyVerifier: Renci.SshNet.Common.SshOperationTimeoutException: Socket read operation has timed out after 30000 milliseconds.
   at Renci.SshNet.Abstractions.SocketAbstraction.Read(Socket socket, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan readTimeout)
   at Renci.SshNet.Connection.ProtocolVersionExchange.SocketReadLine(Socket socket, TimeSpan timeout, List`1 buffer)
   at Renci.SshNet.Connection.ProtocolVersionExchange.Start(String clientVersion, Socket socket, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.CreateAndConnectSession()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
   at liblinux.HostKeyVerifier.Connect(BaseClient client)
11:24:56.0883458 [Error, Thread 1]  liblinux.IO.RemoteFileSystemImpl: Connection failure over SFTP to 127.0.0.1:63718
11:24:56.1130928 [Error, Thread 1]  liblinux.IO.RemoteFileSystemImpl: Renci.SshNet.Common.SshOperationTimeoutException: Socket read operation has timed out after 30000 milliseconds.
   at Renci.SshNet.Abstractions.SocketAbstraction.Read(Socket socket, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan readTimeout)
   at Renci.SshNet.Connection.ProtocolVersionExchange.SocketReadLine(Socket socket, TimeSpan timeout, List`1 buffer)
   at Renci.SshNet.Connection.ProtocolVersionExchange.Start(String clientVersion, Socket socket, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.CreateAndConnectSession()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
   at liblinux.HostKeyVerifier.Connect(BaseClient client)
   at liblinux.IO.RemoteFileSystemImpl.ConnectCore()
11:24:56.1130928 [Info, Thread 1]   liblinux.RemoteSystemBase: Disconnecting over SSH from "127.0.0.1:63718"
```

The SSH connection is working fine because on connect I have to accept the connection fingerprint so the problem is with the SFPT connection happening right after that.

Visual Studio 2022 17.1.6, latest

Any good ideas?

Comment: Please refer [Debugging ASP Core on Linux with Visual Studio 2017](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/debugging-asp-core-on-linux-with-visual-studio-2017/)

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT, I am doing exactly the same thing and the result is in my question... Visual Studio is not able to sftp to the container even though I am able to.  Not to mention that I have to change the MACs in sshd_config everytime because starting from v16.9 Visual studio does not support insecure SSH algorithms but the blessed images in Azure app services are not configured for this... it's a complete nightmare

Comment: Just checking if you had also installed the App Service Extension. None of the links mention it so I must ask.

Comment: @dwellman yep, I have installed it. If I am not mistaken its name is webapp

Comment: @Ivaylo - Did you manage to connect VS to you linux Azure wep app? I am facing the same issue. I am able to SSH suncessfully but not able to connect VS to it.

Comment: @Amit, unfortunately no, I surrendered and moved to a dedicated server. I am really sorry I can't help you because I know how hard is to find info about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

There are two correlated, but rather separate features at play 1) SSH, and 2) Remote Debugging

**SSH**

As of right now, to my knowledge, SSH into *blessed* containers-- code publish-- and *custom* containers-- Docker publish-- is still in "Preview" which means not feature complete, not recommended for production. Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session#open-ssh-session-from-remote-shell) (Open SSH from remote shell). Notably, that doc links [here](https://medium.com/@auchenberg/introducing-remote-debugging-of-node-js-apps-on-azure-app-service-from-vs-code-in-public-preview-9b8d83a6e1f0) (Remote Debugging of Node.js Apps), which suggests Remote Debugging has been enabled for Node.js. However, this blog post is now four years old. Things have probably changed since. So, let's look at the remote debugging feature.

**Remote Debugging**

To tell if Remote Debugging is available for your current runtime and platform, open Azure portal and navigate to the site in question. Under settings Configuration, look for "Debugging" in the General settings tab. You will either be able to enable Remote Debugging (for instance, for Node.js publish, App Service Windows):

[image: Azure App Service Windows, Node 14]

or you will see "Your selected runtime stack does not currently support remote debugging." (for instance, Node.js publish, App Service Linux, .NET 6 publish on App Service Windows):

[image: Azure App Service Windows Dotnet 6]

UPDATE:
Regarding Visual Studio, VS2022 appears to use PORT 4026 as the default port; however, the port for Azure App Service is still 4024. Recent versions of VS appear to have reverted (17.2.0 and later). For versions prior to VS2022 17.2.0, using Debug\Attach, append port 4024 to the connection URL.

Comment: That's why I am trying to SSH to the app service because it's a Linux container running .NET 6 and remote debugging is not available out of the box. As stated here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/3841#issuecomment-529958383 this should be available. 
I have already followed the article you shared. The only problem is that Visual Studio cannot make the SFTP connection to successfully connect to the container and allow remote debugging via SSH

Comment: @Ivaylo So you ARE running a custom container? Did you enable SSH and expose 2222 and are otherwise able to connect from any host?

Comment: it’s not a custom container, I was just trying to use the little info I found.

Comment: You may need to verify the ports VS is using. I updated my answer on the 13th